# Is `utf8` in MariaDB still `utf8mb3`?

Tags: mysql, types, character-encoding, mariadb

From MySQL 8 is `utf8` charset really 4byte `utf8mb4` and not 3byte `utf8mb3`, but what about MariaDB?

Does MariaDB got the same update in some version?

Is it safe to use `utf8` when we need to save characters like emojis nowadays with latest MariaDB/MySQL servers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`utf8` is still `utf8mb3`, and only `utf8mb4` is actual UTF-8. See the documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode.html
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unicode/

This is unlikely to ever change, since it breaks the behaviour of existing code.

Comment: Oracle is threatening to change the meaning of `utf8` in the future, but, as you say, it would be a serious incompatibility.  The safest is to use `utf8mb4` for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to be specific to not cause confusion, use either `utf8mb3`(deprecated in MySQL and also slower there) or `utf8mb4`.

**MariaDB** as per: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unicode/

- 10.6 and later: `utf8` is aliased to `utf8mb4`, but `UTF8_IS_UTF8MB3` is enabled by default through `old_mode`, making `utf8` still resolve to `utf8mb3`.
  `utf8` will become `utf8mb4` in the future as default `old_mode` flags are automatically deprecated.
- 10.5 and earlier: `utf8` is aliased to `utf8mb3`, and only `utf8mb4` is actual UTF-8.

**MySQL** as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode.html

- 8.0 and later: `utf8` is aliased to `utf8mb3`, and only `utf8mb4` is actual UTF-8.
  `utf8mb3` is now deprecated and slated for complete removal, with `utf8` becoming `utf8mb4` in the future.
- 5.7 and earlier: `utf8` is aliased to `utf8mb3`, and only `utf8mb4` is actual UTF-8.